# Lion: Change Background Pictures on all Desktops

Tags: desktop, background-image, osx-lion, wallpaper

I would like to change the wallpaper on all desktops simultaneously to one picture using a shell script (basically anything shell, python, applescript, automator would be fine).

Any hints?

Daniel